# Implementing a semaphore into an Async method

Tags: c#, task, semaphore

Consider that I have the following (very basic) method within my WCF service:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        //do stuff
    });
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the code within the task searches the database, sends emails for the required records and updates a database when sent, however if the call were to be done twice in quick succession then potential duplicates could be sent.

Is it possible to implement semaphores into this method to prevent this given that the UWP app I have written would call the method asynchronously?

Comment: You can use async synchonization primitives from this library: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock (for example).

Comment: Also note that there is nothing "async" if all your WCF method is doing is calling Task.Run. You just exchange one thread pool thread to another with absolutely no benefits.

Comment: @Evk so the simple fact that its an async method would cause it to run on a separte thread anyway? Would that mean calling `await MyMethod()` in the UWP app would be enough, without `Task.Run()` within the wcf service?

Comment: No it's not as simple as that. I cannot explain how to properly use async\await in a comment, you better read it elsewhere. In short - mark your method async AND use async API wherever it is present. For example if you need to open database connection - use `OpenAsync()`. If you need to make a query - use `ReadAsync` (or equivalent). Need to open a file? again `ReadAsync`. If you cannot\don't want to use async api everywhere - just don't use async method in WCF - use regular method (which does not return a task) - you get no benefit from doing that.

Comment: And client-side invocation of your WCF methods is completely separate thing. You can have regular WCF method and invoke it asynchronously at client (UWP app). But as I said - it's hard to properly describe in comments because it's not a trivial subject.

Comment: @Takarii: A better solution would be to update the database to a "processing" state *before* sending the emails.

Answer (score 1):

Create a private field in your class of type [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) and protect the code like so:

```
private Mutex _mutex = new Mutex();
private DateTime _lastRequest = DateTime.MinValue;

...   

public async Task MyMethod()
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        _mutex.WaitOne();
        if(DateTime.Now < _lastRequest + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
            return;

        _lastRequest = DateTime.Now;

        //do stuff
        _mutex.ReleaseMutext();
    });
}
```

Comment: This works...to a degree. If there is a second call then it handles it correctly. However, if there are several calls made it doesnt seem to work the same way. If i call the method twice then this works, however with 3 or more calls the method sends more than the 5 emails I am expecting

Comment: This method will not cancel any request, just simply run them one after the other. If you instead want to to throttle your requests, add an extra check for this. I will update my example.

Comment: I understand. The problem is that the 3rd and further calls seem to be happening before the database is updated, which is before the mutex is released.

Comment: I can't really see how that could happen if your database is updated within the mutex lock, have you verified this? Optionally add a delay within the mutex lock: Task.Delay(100).Wait();

Comment: Realised id made an error in my method call on the App side. I was creating a new service reference with each button click, so naturally it wiped out any stored information relating to the timestamp or the mutex.... Increased the time delay to better handle things, but this appears to be solving the issue for the time being. Thanks